# Should I be able to use gspread with Python to update a cell in Google Sheets with a formula/function?

Tags: python, gspread

I'm trying to set a cell value to a formula/function to use in the Google Sheet, the function will reference other tabs in the workbook. Whenever it updates the cell with the function, it has an apostrophe (') at the beginning of the function. When I remove the apostrophe in Google Sheets, the function performs as I hoped but I'm trying to automate this process.

This is the code I use to set the cell value:

```
func = '=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH("' + c + '", Dictionary!A:A, 0))), VLOOKUP("' + c + '", Dictionary!A:D, 4,FALSE), "' + c + '")'

cells.append(
    Cell(row=rnum+1, col=cnum+1, value=func)
```

The function is sent to the Google Sheet but looks like this, I don't see the apostrophe in the cell until I click on it:
`'=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH("Word", Dictionary!A:A, 0))), VLOOKUP("Word", Dictionary!A:D, 4,FALSE), "Word")`

Is this a bug? When I debug, I am able to see the function as a string with no apostrophes except for those that the object uses to classify it as a string, which makes me wonder if the gspread library is accidentally sending the function to the cell with the apostrophe.

EDIT:
The work around I found was to use update_acell to find the specific cells that needed the formula. It's not perfect but it works for now. I'd still love to know why the extra apostrophe is being added. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

When you put the value of `cells` using `update_cells`, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In this modification, `value_input_option="USER_ENTERED"` is added to `update_cells`. By this, the formula is put to the cell as the formula.
- When `update_cells` is used without `value_input_option="USER_ENTERED"`, the default value of `value_input_option` is `RAW`. By this, `'` is added to the top character of the formula. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

#### Modified script:

```
func = '=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH("' + c + '", Dictionary!A:A, 0))), VLOOKUP("' + c + '", Dictionary!A:D, 4,FALSE), "' + c + '")'
cells.append(Cell(row=rnum+1, col=cnum+1, value=func))

worksheet.update_cells(cells, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")  # Modified
```

#### References:

- [update_cells(cell_list, value_input_option='RAW')](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=update_cells#gspread.models.Worksheet.update_cells)
- [ValueInputOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption)